# How to fix http error 400 with microsoft ASP.NET MVC create command

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

I'm setting up a first C# ASP.NET MVC application using Microsofts tutorial. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio

In the process of this tutorial, it asks to check if the create movies works, but when I attempt to use it, I get an HTTP error 400 - bad request. I believe the data I am entering is accurate, but I can't seem to get anything but a bad request, does anyone know how to fix this.

Model class:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace MvcMovie.Models
{
    public class Movie
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Release Date")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
        public string Genre { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "decimal(18, 2)")]
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Razor view:

```
@model MvcMovie.Models.Movie

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h1>Create</h1>

<h4>Movie</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Title" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Title" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Title" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ReleaseDate" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="ReleaseDate" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ReleaseDate" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Genre" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Genre" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Genre" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Price" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Price" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Price" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Controller action method:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Title,ReleaseDate,Genre,Price")] Movie movie)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Add(movie);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(movie);
    }
```

The expected output is to add to the database, but but the actual output is bad request.

Comment: where is the code which processes the data and adds it to the database, please? This is likely to be in the action method, in your controller. It's that code which will be generating the Bad Request message

Comment: The 400 error basically indicates you are not making a connection with the SQL Server.  So you need to find the connection string and make sure the connection string is correct.  There are a few reasons for the error 1) The SQL Server isn't running or the connection string is connecting to the wrong SQL Server 2) The credentials are wrong. The SQL Server can either use a Windows Credentials which is indicated in the connection string as Integrated Security = true.  Or use a SQL Server Credential 3) The User isn't in the Group Account for the Window Credential.

Comment: @jdweng sorry but how do you infer any of that? Did I miss something? We can't see any server side code. And a 400 error would normally indicate a validation error with the input model data, before it gets anywhere near a database call. A crash due to a database problem I would expect to generate an exception, which would cause the server to output a 500 error, not  a 400

Comment: The SQL server isn't sending the error.  The error is being returned by the server before the connection to the SQL Server.  See : https://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html

Comment: I've added the create requested by ADyson from the controller it's at the bottom of the code. And where would I find that jdweng?

Comment: Not sure it's definitely the cause of the error but `[Bind("Id,Title,ReleaseDate,Genre,Price")]` seems to be redundant...it covers all the fields in your object, so there's no danger of anyone posting anything which isn't desired, and also during a Create you actually don't want to bind to the ID, because it doesn't exist yet, it's not part of your form, the database creates it

Answer (score 0):

Do you have httpPost over method of controller and why you not use model?

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Title,ReleaseDate,Genre,Price")] ....
```

Comment: It does use a model...look again

Answer (score 0):

I was using google chrome, and firefox. Apparently it won't let me test on anything except edge or IE